# GeoIP2 Call returns "INVALID_LICENSE_KEY"

Tags: ip, geoip, maxmind

I apologize in advance if this is a silly question. I've been trying to solve this for a few hours now with no success.

I bought 50,000 GeoIP City queries.

When I try calling via http://geoip.maxmind.com/e?l=my_license>&i=my_IP 
I get "INVALID_LICENSE_KEY"

I'm thinking maybe that's because I should be using the GeoIP2 not GeoIP calls? 
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/web-services/

If so can someone please help me structure my url call because I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using the GeoIP Legacy web service. The endpoint you are calling is for the Omni service, not the City service according to the [developer documentation](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/web-services/). Try using:

```
https://geoip.maxmind.com/b?l={license_key}&i={ip_address}
```

If you want to use the GeoIP2 web service, I would suggest using one of the [supported client APIs](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/web-services/#Client_APIs).

Answer (score 0):

try GeoIP Legacy web service:

```
https://geoip.maxmind.com/e?l={license_key}&i={ip_address}
```